# Using yahoo finance with python

Tags: python, finance

I am having issues taking the sp100 list off of wikepdia and creating a line of code that will then take that list and get the historical prices off of yahoo finance.

Here is the exzct prompt, I can't seem to figure it out.

Download the list of S&P 100 companies from Wikipedia and their historical prices from Yahoo Finance. Estimate the mean return and covariance matrix of these stocks. Download the risk-free rate from FRED and calculate the average risk-free rate.

Instructions:

Use pd.read_html() to download the list of S&P 100 companies from Wikipedia.
Download the history of monthly prices of these companies from Yahoo Finance.
Calculate the monthly returns for each stock based on the historical prices. Go back to Jan 2010 when the data are available.
Estimate the mean return and covariance matrix of these stocks.
Use the pandas_datareader library to download the one-month T-bill rates since Jan 2010 from FRED. The relevant series code for one-month T-bill rates is DGS1MO.
Calculate the average T-Bill rate over the period, which will be used as the risk-free rate.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import yfinance as yf
from pandas_datareader import data as web
from pandas_datareader.famafrench import get_available_datasets


yf.pdr_override()

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%26P_100"
sp100_data = pd.read_html(url)


sp100_table = sp100_data[2]

sp100_tickers = sp100_table["Symbol"].tolist()


start_date = "2010-01-01"
end_date = "2023-10-27"  
price_data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(sp100_tickers, start_date, end_date)


monthly_returns = price_data["Adj Close"].pct_change().dropna()


mean_returns = monthly_returns.mean()
cov_matrix = monthly_returns.cov()


t_bill_rates = pdr.DataReader("DGS1MO", "fred", start_date, end_date)


average_rf_rate = t_bill_rates.mean()[0]


print("Mean Returns:")
print(mean_returns)
print("\nCovariance Matrix:")
print(cov_matrix)
print(f"\nAverage Risk-Free Rate: {average_rf_rate}%")
```

Error:Mean Returns:
AAPL   NaN
ABBV   NaN
ABT    NaN
ACN    NaN
ADBE   NaN
..
V      NaN
VZ     NaN
WFC    NaN
WMT    NaN
XOM    NaN
Length: 101, dtype: float64

Covariance Matrix:
AAPL  ABBV  ABT  ACN  ADBE  AIG  AMD  AMGN  AMT  AMZN  ...  TXN  UNH  
AAPL   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN
ABBV   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN
ABT    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN
ACN    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN
ADBE   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN
...    ...   ...  ...  ...   ...  ...  ...   ...  ...   ...  ...  ...  ...
V      NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN
VZ     NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN
WFC    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN
WMT    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN
XOM    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN

```
  UNP  UPS  USB   V  VZ  WFC  WMT  XOM
```

AAPL  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
ABBV  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
ABT   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
ACN   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
ADBE  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
...   ...  ...  ...  ..  ..  ...  ...  ...
V     NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
VZ    NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
WFC   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
WMT   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
XOM   NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

[101 rows x 101 columns]

Average Risk-Free Rate: nan%

Comment: You really need to show enough code that someone can reproduce the error you are getting. Telling us the prompt is only useful in making a bunch of old timers shake their heads in dismay.

Comment: You can get it using the yfinance download! `price_data = yf.download(sp100_tickers, start_date, end_date)`

Comment: @r-beginners it is still giving me the same error

Comment: I ran it on the latest version of yfinance:0.2.31. Errors occur when some discontinued issues are included in the target period, but all other issues could be retrieved.

Comment: 2@r-beginners thank you so much